# detect which annotation callout disclosure button is pushed

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, uiviewcontroller, annotations

I am trying to detect which annotation disclosure button is pressed in order to display specific information for that location in DetailController. This information is parsed in JSon, any suggestions on how to detect which annotation is selected and then parse the correct information to DetailController? Here is my ViewController.m file

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "DetailController.h"
#import "Annotation.h"

#import "City.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet DetailController *detailViewController;


@end
#define getDatalURL @"http://www.club-hop.com/apptest.php"

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize mapView,jsonArray,citiesArray;

/*-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"clubName"]){
    NSString * name= @"clubName";
    NSString * line= @"clubLine";

    DetailViewController *dv= [segue destinationViewController];
    dv.cName=name;
    dv.cLine=line;
}
}*/



- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
[self retrieveData];
self.detailViewController = [[DetailController alloc] init];
/* Zoom the map to current location.
[self.mapView setShowsUserLocation:YES];
[self.mapView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
[self.mapView setUserTrackingMode:MKUserTrackingModeFollow];*/
City * cityObject;

// load external page into UIWebView
NSMutableArray * locations= [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
CLLocationCoordinate2D location;
Annotation * myAnn;

for(int u=0; u<citiesArray.count;u++){
cityObject=[citiesArray objectAtIndex:u];

myAnn=[[Annotation alloc]init];
NSNumber *aLat= cityObject.Latitude;
NSNumber *aLon= cityObject.Longitude;

double lat = [aLat doubleValue];
double lon = [aLon doubleValue];

location.latitude= lat;
location.longitude=lon;
myAnn.coordinate = location;
myAnn.title=cityObject.clubName;
myAnn.subtitle=cityObject.cityName;
[locations addObject:myAnn];}

[self.mapView addAnnotations:locations];


}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}



//class methods
-(void) retrieveData{
NSURL * url= [NSURL URLWithString:getDatalURL];
NSData * data= [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
jsonArray= [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];

//setup cities array
citiesArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

for(int i=0; i<jsonArray.count;i++){
    NSString * cID= [[jsonArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"id"];
    NSString * cName= [[jsonArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"cityName"];
    NSString * cCountry= [[jsonArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"cityCountry"];
    NSString * cLine= [[jsonArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"clubLine"];
    NSString * clName= [[jsonArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"clubName"];
    NSNumber * cLatitude= [[jsonArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"Latitude"];
    NSNumber * cLongitude= [[jsonArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"Longitude"];

    [citiesArray addObject:[[City alloc]initWithCityName:cName andCityCountry:cCountry  andClubName:clName andClubLine:cLine andLatitude:cLatitude andLongitude:cLongitude andCityId:cID]];

}

}
```

#pragma mark - MKMapViewDelegate

```
// user tapped the disclosure button in the callout
//
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view   calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control

{   

UIStoryboard* storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard"
                                                       bundle:nil];
 self.detailViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Page2"];
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.detailViewController animated:YES];

}

- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id  <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{

MKPinAnnotationView* pinView = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[mapView  dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"pinView"];

if (!pinView)
{
    pinView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation  reuseIdentifier:@"pinView"] ;
    pinView.pinColor=MKPinAnnotationColorGreen;
    pinView.animatesDrop=YES;
    pinView.canShowCallout=YES;
    UIButton * rightButton= [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
    pinView.rightCalloutAccessoryView=rightButton;
}
else{
    pinView.annotation=annotation;
}
return pinView;

    }


@end
```

Comment: You get the annotation returned to you in - (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view   calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `City` property to both your `AnnotationView` and your `detailViewController` classes -

In detailViewController.h and in AnnotationView.h add

```
@class City;

@property (strong,nonatomic) City *city;
```

In  `viewDidLoad` for your ViewController.m file replace your current 'for' loop with the following

```
for (int u=0; u<citiesArray.count;u++) {
    cityObject=[citiesArray objectAtIndex:u];

    myAnn=[[Annotation alloc]init];

    myAnn.city=cityObject;           // Store the city object on the annotation

    NSNumber *aLat= cityObject.Latitude;
    NSNumber *aLon= cityObject.Longitude;

    double lat = [aLat doubleValue];
    double lon = [aLon doubleValue];

    location.latitude= lat;
    location.longitude=lon;
    myAnn.coordinate = location;
    myAnn.title=cityObject.clubName;
    myAnn.subtitle=cityObject.cityName;

    [locations addObject:myAnn];
}
```

Alternatively you create a new `initWithCity:city` method for your annotation and just call that and have the initialiser set up all of the other annotation properties.  This would be the new 'for' loop in your `viewDidLoad` method in ViewController.m

```
for (int u=0; u<citiesArray.count;u++) {
        cityObject=[citiesArray objectAtIndex:u];

        myAnn=[[Annotation alloc]initWithCity:cityObject];

        [locations addObject:myAnn];
    }
```

In annotation.m

```
#import "City.h"

-(id)initWithCity:(City *)city
{
        self=[super init];

        if (self) {
           self.city=city;           // Store the city object on the annotation

        NSNumber *aLat= city.Latitude;
        NSNumber *aLon= city.Longitude;

        double lat = [aLat doubleValue];
        double lon = [aLon doubleValue];

        CLLocationCoordinate2D location;

        location.latitude= lat;
        location.longitude=lon;
        self.coordinate = location;
        self.title=city.clubName;
        self.subtitle=city.cityName;

     }
     return (self);
}
```

Either way your `calloutAccessoryControlTapped:` in ViewController.m becomes -

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view   calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control

{   

    UIStoryboard* storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard"
                                                       bundle:nil];
    self.detailViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Page2"];

    Annotation *myAnnotation=(Annotation *)view.annotation;

    self.detailViewController.city=myAnnotation.city;

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.detailViewController animated:YES];

}
```